# Got an error: The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value?

Tags: powerbi

I looked at the example from:

https://businessintelligist.com/2017/03/27/market-basket-analysis-using-power-bi/

My attempt:

```
Market Basket = CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(Sales, Sales[KdItem], "-", FILTER(ALL(Sales), Sales[NoTrans]=EARLIER(Sales[NoTrans]))))
```

My attempt did not work.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you  give us a sample of your data?

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the closing bracket after the delimiter `"-"` of the CONCATENATEX function. So try this:

```
Market Basket =
CALCULATE (
    CONCATENATEX ( Sales, Sales[KdItem], "-" ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Sales ), Sales[NoTrans] = EARLIER ( Sales[NoTrans] ) )
)
```